# Centering images in a row

Tags: css, image, row, center

Im looking to have images centred in a row on http://justinstephens.co under the 'contact us' section.

Probably a simple resolution but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to research your questions. If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: well, I can't do more than this: ADD margin to first li element. `li:first-child { margin:0 0 0 30%; }` works on 1024x768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

The solution below was done in Chrome with live editing. After further investigation, it appears your CSS file adds a margin to `#contact-images`. Removing this margin will allow the solution below to work.

```
#contact-images {
    /*margin-left: 190px;*/
    text-align: center; 
}
```

---

This will center the `<ul>` under Contact us:

```
<div id="contact-images" style="text-align: center;">
```

There remains a slight misalignment. Remove the padding to the `<ul>` element to fix this.

```
<ul style="padding: 0 0 0 0;">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this does not seem to work. I have "text-align: center;" on all other text, although for some reason the contact sections seems to not align with the rest of the site.

Comment: That's because your CSS file has `#contact-images { margin-left: 190px; }`. Remove that and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align:center` to the element with the id `contact-images`. The following is only for demonstration purpose:

```
<div id="contact-images" style="text-align: center;"> [...] </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this does not seem to work. I have "text-align: center;" on all other text, although for some reason the contact sections seems to not align with the rest of the site.